Facing trouble when implementing websockets
I am trying to implement web sockets in my Node.js application.
config/socket.js
The initialization of socket, and an emit notification function.
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const winston = require('./winston');
const notificationHandler = require('./socketHandlers/notification');
const roomHandler = require('./socketHandlers/room');

let io;

const initializeSocket = (server) => {
    io = socketIO(server, {
        cors: {
            origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
            methods: ["GET", "POST"]
        }
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('A user connected:', socket.id);
        winston.info('A user connected:', socket.id);

        // Handle notification-related events
        notificationHandler(io, socket);

        // Handle room-related events
        roomHandler(io, socket);

        // Handle disconnection
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('User disconnected:', socket.id);
        });
    });
};

const emitNotification = (userId, notification) => {
    if (io) {
        io.to(`user_${userId}`).emit('new_notification', notification);
        console.log(`Emitting notification to user ${userId}`);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    initializeSocket,
    emitNotification
};


config/socketHandlers/room.js
module.exports = (io, socket) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom', (userId) => {
        if (io) {
            const room = `user_${userId}`;
            socket.join(room);
            console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} joined room ${room}`);
        } else {
            console.log('Socket.io is not initialized');
        }
    });
};


config/socketHandlers/notification.js
const notificationUtils = require('../../modules/notification/notification.utils');

module.exports = (io, socket) => {
    socket.on('notification_received', async (notificationId) => {
        try {
            if (io) {
                await notificationUtils.markAsDelivered(notificationId);

                console.log(`Notification ID ${notificationId} marked as delivered.`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Failed to update delivery status for notification ID ${notificationId}:`, error);
        }
    });
};

When I comment out the notificationHandler from the socket.js file, the application works fine. But when I uncomment that part, it crashes. And I can't seem to find the cause.
The code for the notificationHandler intends to update the delivered field of a notification to true when the frontend receives a notification.
